# Syncing data from field maps to ArcGIS Pro with multiple users

Tags: arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-field-maps

So I am in charge of getting GIS set up for a small business. I was curious if you all think you need to have an enterprise geodatabase if you have multiple people out in the field editing data using the ESRI field maps app? I am asking as I am trying to choose between the Basic and Advanced ArcGIS Pro packages for the company as they do not need to the more high end analysis tools.

Comment: You should have a look at using Arcgis online as an alternative to setting up an enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: You don't really need an enterprise geodatabase for users going out in the field and collecting data, rather use ArcGIS Online capabilities for this.

Comment: 'Advanced' and 'Enterprise' are not comparable, are not dependent on each other, and shouldn't be confused with each other.  You can have Enterprise without Advanced, and vice versa.  Having said that, I don't think you need either, so long as you can use ArcGIS Online, instead of Enterprise.